# lennox furnace not working pilot light on but burner doesn't start

Tags: furnace

lennox furnace, model # G20Q2E-75-C1, serial #6392H32332, pilot light lights, blower motor turns on, burner doesn't burn

Comment: Is the thermostat on?  Is the thermostat getting power (or the batteries good)?  Is the thermostat calling for heat?

Comment: Can you hear the main gas valve open (probably a click, clank, or ping) a bit after the pilot has been lit? Can you hear gas flowing?

Comment: Does this model have an electronic pilot, or do you manually light the pilot (always burning)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the Troubleshooting flow chart from the [user manual](http://www.completeheating.ca/Old/manuals/LennoxG20.pdf)?

[image: Troubleshooting flowchart]
<sup>*Click for larger view*</sup>

You'll probably want to start with this bit...

[image]

Specifically, if the unit hasn't started in a bit (over the summer), I'd try cleaning the area of the burner nearest the pilot.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a limit switch is preventing burner ignition.
Look for code flash on led light on control board.

Comment: What makes you suspect a limit switch? How would you determine if a limit switch was not working properly?

Answer (score -2):

Jump it, if it allows you, and check for continuity and check for 24V.